# XSLT/ Xpath how to accumulate / get total of a node based on a condition in another node

Tags: xpath, sum

I need to get two totals `CreditCardTotal` and `CashTotal` and have to display them in another tag `AccountCost`, as shown below.

Basically, I need get the expense amount and check to see if it is a credit card or cash and then add it to the respective total variable. Or if there is a more elegant way please let me know.

I am completely stumped and new to Xpath. Thanks, and will truly appreciate your time and effort.

```
<ExpenseCatDetail>
    <Expense>500</Expense>
    <PaymentMethod>CreditCard</PaymentMethod>
    <AccountCost>700</AccountCost>
</ExpenseCatDetail>

<ExpenseCatDetail>     
     <Expense>100</Expense>
     <PaymentMethod>Cash</PaymentMethod>
     <AccountCost>400</AccountCost>
</ExpenseCatDetail>

<ExpenseCatDetail>
    <Expense>200</Expense>
    <PaymentMethod>CreditCard</PaymentMethod>
    <AccountCost>700</AccountCost>
</ExpenseCatDetail>

<ExpenseCatDetail>
   <Expense>300</Expense>
   <PaymentMethod>Cash</PaymentMethod>
   <AccountCost>400</AccountCost>
</ExpenseCatDetail>
```

Answer (score 1):

Element construction is not possible with XPath, you would require XQuery for that.

To fetch a single sum, use

```
sum(//ExpenseCatDetail[PaymentMethod="Cash"]/AccountCost)
```

and replace "Cash" as needed.

Using XPath 2.0, you could at least calculate both sums in one statement and return a sequence  of both values (is usually mapped to an array or similar construct in other programming languages):

```
(
  sum(//ExpenseCatDetail[PaymentMethod="Cash"]/AccountCost),
  sum(//ExpenseCatDetail[PaymentMethod="CreditCard"]/AccountCost)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Jens Erat, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: And what would be the function to concatenate string values?

Comment: Use `concat($string, $string, ...)` for a fixed (but arbitrary) number of strings (no sequences), `string-join($seq, $seperator)` for sequences of strings which get concatenated with `$seperator` in-between. `string-join` is only available in XPath 2.0 (and upwards),  `concat` can also be used in XPath 1.0.